# Add SPListItem with file

Tags: 2010, splistitem, file-upload, splist, spfile

I have a library, that have items and each item has additional `File` field.

I can upload them programmicaly - firsly file is uploaded, then empty item is updated with other info.

Example of filled item:

> < z:row xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema' ows_ContentTypeId='0x010100A5914B6F2BB5492BBAF497E66640A8990050C4F6DFA243FB4080ABA9EF719BCA65'
>   ows_FileLeafRef='8;#debug.log'
>   ows_Modified_x0020_By='SHAREPOINT\system'
>   ows_Created_x0020_By='SHAREPOINT\system' ows_File_x0020_Type='log'
>   ows_Title='dghdfg' ows_PublicDocument_FullName='dghdfgh'
>   ows_PublicDocument_Type='Официальное уведомление органа, проводящего
>   расследование' ows_PublicDocument_Number='127055'
>   ows_PublicDocument_Investigations='1;#1;#2;#2;#3;#3'
>   ows_PublicDocument_Investigations_Nav='<a
>   href="/ru/act/trade/podm/Inv1207/1">1</a>; <a
>   href="/ru/act/trade/podm/Inv1207/2">2</a>; <a
>   href="/ru/act/trade/podm/Inv1207/3">3</a>'
>   ows_PublicDocument_Published='2016-02-19 00:00:00' ows_ID='8'
>   ows_ContentType='Публичный документ' ows_Created='2016-02-19 14:48:15'
>   ows_Author='1073741823;#Системная учетная запись'
>   ows_Modified='2016-02-19 14:48:55' ows_Editor='1073741823;#Системная
>   учетная запись' ows__ModerationStatus='0'
>   ows_FileRef='8;#ru/act/trade/podm/Inv1207/PublicDocuments/debug.log'
>   ows_FileDirRef='8;#ru/act/trade/podm/Inv1207/PublicDocuments'
>   ows_Last_x0020_Modified='8;#2016-02-19 14:48:55'
>   ows_Created_x0020_Date='8;#2016-02-19 14:48:16'
>   ows_File_x0020_Size='8;#7381' ows_FSObjType='8;#0'
>   ows_SortBehavior='8;#0' ows_PermMask='0x400001f07fff1bff'
>   ows_CheckedOutUserId='8;#' ows_IsCheckedoutToLocal='8;#0'
>   ows_UniqueId='8;#{07AEA512-E9CE-4CED-95E3-412B8F909F8A}'
>   ows_ProgId='8;#'
>   ows_ScopeId='8;#{79A0C68F-5687-43E3-95FF-3C74890D21FB}'
>   ows_VirusStatus='8;#7381' ows_CheckedOutTitle='8;#'
>   ows__CheckinComment='8;#' ows__EditMenuTableStart='debug.log'
>   ows__EditMenuTableStart2='8' ows__EditMenuTableEnd='8'
>   ows_LinkFilenameNoMenu='debug.log' ows_LinkFilename='debug.log'
>   ows_LinkFilename2='debug.log' ows_DocIcon='log'
>   ows_ServerUrl='/ru/act/trade/podm/Inv1207/PublicDocuments/debug.log'
>   ows_EncodedAbsUrl='http://localhost/ru/act/trade/podm/Inv1207/PublicDocuments/debug.log'
>   ows_BaseName='debug' ows_FileSizeDisplay='7381'
>   ows_MetaInfo='8;#vti_parserversion:SR|14.0.0.7149
> PublicDocument_Published:SW|2016-02-19T00:00:00Z
> vti_folderitemcount:IR|0
> ContentTypeId:SW|0x010100A5914B6F2BB5492BBAF497E66640A8990050C4F6DFA243FB4080ABA9EF719BCA65
> vti_title:SW|dghdfg
> vti_author:SR|SHAREPOINT\system
> PublicDocument_Investigations_Nav:SW|<a
>   href='/ru/act/trade/podm/Inv1207/1'>1</a>; <a
>   href='/ru/act/trade/podm/Inv1207/2'>2</a>; <a
>   href='/ru/act/trade/podm/Inv1207/3'>3</a>
> PublicDocument_FullName:SW|dghdfgh
> PublicDocument_Number:SW|127055
> PublicDocument_Type:SW|Официальное
>   уведомление органа, проводящего
>   расследование
> PublicDocument_Investigations:SW|1;#1;#2;#2;#3;#3
> vti_modifiedby:SR|SHAREPOINT\system
> vti_foldersubfolderitemcount:IR|0
> '
>   ows__Level='1' ows__IsCurrentVersion='1' ows_ItemChildCount='8;#0'
>   ows_FolderChildCount='8;#0' ows_SelectTitle='8' ows_SelectFilename='8'
>   ows_Edit='0' ows_owshiddenversion='2' ows__UIVersion='512'
>   ows__UIVersionString='1.0' ows_Order='800.000000000000'
>   ows_GUID='{B6216FC1-0FA4-4356-AA53-988A7CFBE65F}'
>   ows_WorkflowVersion='1' ows_ParentVersionString='8;#'
>   ows_ParentLeafName='8;#'
>   Etag="{07AEA512-E9CE-4CED-95E3-412B8F909F8A},2" ows_Combine='0'
>   ows_RepairDocument='0' ows_ServerRedirected='0' />

Now I want to upload it programmicaly. I do it like that:

```
var docs = web.Lists[publicDocumentsName];
var item = docs.AddItem();
item["PublicDocument_FullName"] = value.Name;
item["PublicDocument_Number"] = value.No;
item.File.SaveBinary(value.Data);
```

where Value.Data is `byte[]` - file body. But it doesn't work.
Every example I found are about documents library where files are the items itselfs, but in my case it's just an attachment. But it's not a true attachment, becuase as I can see it's added as `File` property, when attachments are empty.
    item.Update();

Answer (score 0):

This code adds a file and then fills all fields. Thanks to google and this site, I found several good ideas here and somewhere on the internet:

```
var docs = web.Lists[listName]; // get list
var file = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(filePath), value.Data); // upload file
file.Item["PublicDocument_FullName"] = fileName; // modify custom fields
file.Item["PublicDocument_Number"] = value.No;
file.Item["PublicDocument_Type"] = value.Type;
file.Item["PublicDocument_Published"] = value.PublishedDateTime;
file.Item["PublicDocument_Investigations"] = GetInvestigationsLookup(value.Investigations);
file.Item.Update(); // update item
file.Update(); // update file
```